# Goroutine synchronization with Mutex

Tags: go, mutex, goroutine

```
    var n int32 = 0
    var mutex *sync.Mutex = new(sync.Mutex)

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        go func() {
            mutex.Lock()
            defer mutex.Unlock()
            atomic.AddInt32(&n, 1)

        }()
    }

    fmt.Println(n)
```

I'm wondering why the result of `n` is not 100000, looks like the mutex lock does not work.

Comment: The mutex does ensure that atomic.AddInt32(&n, 1) is called synchronously, but it's not needed. The atomic.AddIn32 function can be called concurrently with the same pointer value.  The problem is that  `fmt.Println(n)` is executed before the goroutines complete.

Comment: Fix by using a [wait group](https:///godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup): https://go.dev/play/p/80by0rYnRr5

Comment: Is there performance discrepancy between Mutex and `atomic.AddInt32()` https://go.dev/play/p/GaIfgglBDzY

Comment: They do different things. A mutex ensures goroutine synchronization, atomic only ensures safe concurrent access.

Answer (score 2):

fmt.Println(n) is executing before the go threads completion,You need to add the time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond) before fmt.Println(n) like below

```
   package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "sync/atomic"
        "time"
    )
    
    func main() {
        var n int32 = 0
        var mutex *sync.Mutex = new(sync.Mutex)
    
        for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
            go func() {
                mutex.Lock()
                defer mutex.Unlock()
                atomic.AddInt32(&n, 1)
    
            }()
        }
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
Output :
--------
100000
```

Or

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    var n int32 = 0
    var mutex *sync.Mutex = new(sync.Mutex)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            mutex.Lock()
            defer mutex.Unlock()
            atomic.AddInt32(&n, 1)
            wg.Done()

        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(n)
}

Output :
--------
100000
```

Comment: As per comment to the original question, there is a proper way to wait for the loop/goroutines to complete, not introduce an arbitrary delay.

Comment: Yes we can do by using wait groups also:



package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "sync"
 "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
 var n int32 = 0
 var mutex *sync.Mutex = new(sync.Mutex)
 var wg sync.WaitGroup

 for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
   mutex.Lock()
   defer mutex.Unlock()
   atomic.AddInt32(&n, 1)
   wg.Done()

  }()
 }
 wg.Wait()
 fmt.Println(n)
}